# SVG link is present but not being link-i-fied

Tags: svg, hyperlink

Can anyone tell me why my SVG link is not being linkified? The  tag is present, and wrapping the text node but just not having any effect. The snippet of SVG is:

```html
<a xlink:href="http://www.abcharts.net">
  <text x="600" y="250" fill="black" text-anchor="end" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt">abcharts.net</text>
</a>
```

And if you wish you can see it in action here:

http://abcharts.net

Comment: try wrapping `<text>` inside `<svg>`

Comment: Its inside a full SVG tag, that's just a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

abcharts contains this function:

```
//
// Create an SVG object
//
AB.create = function (args)
{
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', args.tag);

    for (var i in args.attrs) {
        if (typeof i === 'string') {
            el.setAttribute(i, args.attrs[i]);
        }
    }

    args.object.svg.appendChild(el);

    return el;
};
```

This is only able to create objects in the null namespace (since it uses setAttribute and not setAttributeNS).

When this function is passed the xlink:href attribute it does not, therefore create it correctly so the link does not work.

The correct way to set an xlink:href attribute is

```
el.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', attrs[i]);
```

Comment: You sir - are my hero. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Khanh TO is right, needs a svg tag. here is a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/Sam558/o93m6Lfz/).

```
<svg>
<a xlink:href="http://www.abcharts.net">
  <text x="10" y="20" fill="black" text-anchor="end" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt">abcharts.net</text>
</a>
</svg>
```